# takePictureAsync of Expo's Camera returns nothing. (Promise never fulfilled)

Tags: android, react-native, camera, expo

I started using `Camera` from Expo for React Native (https://docs.expo.io/versions/v35.0.0/sdk/camera/)

I see camera window but when I call `await this.camera.takePictureAsync();` the Promise is never finished and I get no output.

My camera:

```
<Camera ref={(camera) => this.camera = camera}
  style={{flex: 1}}
  type={this.state.type}
>
  <Button onPress={() => this.snap()} title='SNAP'/>
</Camera>
```

Snap function:

```
snap = async () => {
  if (this.camera) {
      console.log("SNAP!");
      let photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
      console.log(photo);
  }
};
```

The `SNAP!` is shown in console so there is no problem with camera itself. Second `console.log` is never called.

I am testing my app on Android 9 (Real device)

**EDIT: It is working on emulator, so there must be problem specifically with the real device**

Comment: Hi, same problem here, were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set  useCamera2Api prop to true for Camera element.